# Docker compose for multiple different projects

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following projects structure on my machine filesystem:

```
../
├── angular_front_end/
│   └── docker-compose.yml
│   └── Dockerfile
├── node_back_end_service/
│   └── docker-compose.yml
│   └── Dockerfile
└── php_back_end_service/
    └── docker-compose.yml
    └── Dockerfile
```

The thing is, I don't want to go through each one and do `docker-compose up`, it's horrible to maintain.
Is there a way to unite them all under one command somehow?

Also, can I run all of them under one container, like the `back-end` container in the screenshot below?

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can have multiple frontends and backends in a single docker file.

Comment: I guess you are using windows, so a `.bat` script calling `project_path/docker-compose up -d`  would do the job.

Comment: @leopal Using macOS :)

Comment: @Ashok But there are no example of such things anywhere. Every tutorial I find is doing stuff completely different and all of the examples are too basic.

Comment: Create a docker-compose.yml file in your project folder and it will define the services in your app so that they can run together in an isolated environment

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single `docker-compose.yml` file at the root of this directory hierarchy that launches everything.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  frontend:
    # Builds Dockerfile within that directory,
    # can only reference files within this directory
    build: angular_front_end
    ports: ['3000:3000']
  node:
    build: node_back_end
  php:
    build: php_back_end
```

To the extent that these services require databases or other Docker resources, they all need to be duplicated in this top-level `docker-compose.yml` file.

In principle it's possible to reuse your existing Compose files, but there are two big issues you'll run into.  You need to consistently use multiple `docker-compose -f` options, *every* time you run a `docker-compose` command; with your setup this will quickly become unwieldy (even with just three services).  Also, [all filesystem paths are interpreted relative to the first `-f` option's path](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files) so a declaration like `build: .` won't point at the right place.

Comment: "You need to consistently use multiple docker-compose -f options, every time you run a docker-compose command;" what's wrong with creating a docker-compose wrapper script that handles this for you though? It's one file to maintain if you need to add another `-f new-project/docker-compose.yml`